# A custom file class. Is this feasible?

Tags: python

Currently I'm reading and writing binary files and am calling the struct pack/unpack functions frequently. Rather than constantly having to write something like

`struct.unpack("3f", myFile.read(12))`

I decided to write a function to save myself some typing, so the equivalent of the above statement in my code is

`my_unpack(myFile, '3f')`

Where my_unpack is defined as

`struct.unpack(fmt, f.read(struct.calcsize(fmt))`

But then I'm thinking what if I instead wrote things like

```
myFile.get_float(3)
myFile.get_char(12)
myFile.get_string(20)
```

It would make it a little easier to read I believe, especially since the syntax for packing and unpacking might look daunting for those that are not familiar with it.

Would this be enough reason to write my own class that inherits the File class **just to provide a couple extra methods?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't subclass.  Instead, compose:

```
class StructReader(object):
    def __init__(self, input_file):
        self.input_file = input_file

    def get_float(self, n):
        fmt = ...
        return struct.unpack(fmt, self.input_file.read(struct.calcsize(fmt)))

    ...
```

When you subclass, you have to worry about namespace collisions.  Composition avoids this problem.

Comment: oh, I didn't know about it. That makes it easier then!

Answer (score 3):

The concept you are detailing is called a Wrapper, it implements the [Facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) design pattern. The reason for the existence of wrappers is to make calling methods on the parent class easier - exactly what you want to do. I don't see a problem with it.

Comment: hm, I'm not so sure about the Facade pattern. Anyway, wrapper put a layer of abstraction above the class you are wrapping, making it easier to work with it.

Answer (score 2):

In general - yes, why not?

But why would you want to inherit from File? Why not use composition / break dependencies?

```
class BinaryReader(object):
    def __init__(self, source):
        self.source = source

    def read_char(l):
        fmt = str(l) + 'c'
        data = self.source.read(struct.calcsize(fmt))
        return struct.unpack(fmt, data)
    ....
```